# how can i run linux commands from PyGTK?

Tags: python, linux, terminal, command, gtk

so, i need to run linux commands from my PyGTK application. what i want is what i could do with other programming languages: sending a specific command with all its arguments to the core of the operating system so that it is run as it was entered in a terminal.

ive tried to find a solution everywhere, but the only thing that i found was a library called VTE that provides a method called "fork_command_full" that is suppose to do this. so, the deal here would be to create a virtual terminal, and then send a command to be run in it, rather than sending it to the core of the operating system.

thing is, i cant find out how a command can be passed as an argument or however it is done with this function. [documentation](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/api/Vte_2.90/classes/Terminal.html?highlight=vte#Vte.Terminal.fork_command_full).

Comment: Look at python os.popen() or os.system() commands.

Comment: Use the `subprocess` module. Don't even think of using stuff from `os` to execute programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

os.system() is the solution. i was trying to find in PyGTK, while it was as right in the python module "os". here is the documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system

Answer (score 0):

You may want [gobject.spawn_async](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html) etc.. which is wrapping in Python the [spawning processes](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html) Glib functions.